# How to take user input for matrix in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote the whole code, just in the place of `x` and `y`, this has to take input from user:

```
import numpy as np

A= np.array([[1,1],[2,4]])

print (A)

b = np.array([x,y])

z=np.linalg.solve(A,b)

print(z)
```

Comment: See [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the shape of matrix and only need two elements, you can input them individually.
You have to typecast accordingly, if they are integers.

```
x = int(input("Enter x: "))
y = int(input("Enter y: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the input value from the user in python as ,

```
x=input("Enter value of x :")
```

similarly for y ,

```
y=input("Enter value of y")
```

But this takes the value of x & y as string . so if you want to take the input in integer you must typecast the input as,

```
x=int(input("Enter value of x :"))
```

similarly for y ,

```
y=int(input("Enter value of y :"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this :-

```
import numpy as np
x = int(input("input number of rows: "))
y = int(input("input number of cols: "))
arr = np.array([ [ input() for i in range(y) ] for j in range(x) ])
print(arr)
```

Where (x,y) is the shape of the matrix, needed to be initiated before this.